# Log odds Standard Error?

Tags: logistic, standard-error, odds-ratio, odds

I am reading a paper on how the authors calculate the variance/standard deviation of what appears to be log(odds).

The paper is a medical paper (Discontinuation of Oral Antivirals in Chronic Hepatitis B: A Systematic Review).

In the paper, it seems that they are doing something equivalent of log(odds) by using $\log(p/(1-p))$.

However, I don't understand how they get the variance to be $1/[Np(1-p)]$.

I am confused by other sources stating that the standard deviation of log odds is supposed to be $\sqrt{1/a+1/b+1/c+1/d}$. For instance, [How do I calculate the standard deviation of the log-odds?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/266098/how-do-i-calculate-the-standard-deviation-of-the-log-odds).

Are the two approaches the same or different? Which is correct?

[image: cited text as pdf]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\hat Var(log(\frac p{1-p})) \approx \frac 1 {Np(1-p)}$$

$$\hat Var\left[log\left(\frac {p_1/(1-p_1)}{p_2/(1-p_2)}\right)\right] \approx \frac 1 a + \frac 1 b+ \frac 1 c +\frac 1 d$$
where $p = X/N$ is estimate of parameter $\pi$ in $X\sim Bin(\pi,n)$

First one is for log ODDS, and second one is for log ODDS RATIO. In the linked page, OP misused ODDS.