# Weighting pharmacovigilance data in a meta-regression

Tags: weights, meta-regression, survey-weights

I would like to run a meta-regression in which the independent variable is composed of weighted reported odds ratios (ie, the number of events for a particular medication side effect divided by total events reported for that med) and the dependent variable is a set of effect sizes. However, I have an issue with the reported odds ratios in that some of them are based off a much greater number of events than others (eg, a reported odds ratio based off 10 total side effects for a med vs. a reported odds ratio based off 1000s of total side effects for a med) and I would like to account for this through weights. Does anyone know how to do this? Thank you for any help!

Comment: Set the weights proportional to the variance of each estimate.

Comment: Sorry, would you mind getting more specific? I have somewhat rudimentary stats knowledge.

Comment: (meant to say inversely proportional to variance). The idea of using weights for regression makes sense to you (I suspect upon reading this question, but lmk if im wrong). So you just need to calcluate the variance of each of your log-odds, using for example the ideas here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/266098/how-do-i-calculate-the-standard-deviation-of-the-log-odds and then plug the inverse of that into the weights parameter of your regression package.

Comment: Ah, okay. I understand what you mean. After calculating that weight, do you have any sense of how I might apply it to a meta-regression (ie apply weights to the independent variable in the meta-regression)? The meta-regression programs I am aware of only allow weights to be added to the dependent variable.

Comment: Oh I see it in the independent variables, the term to google there is Error in Variables regression. You should be able to use those as the variance of those ratios as the variance of independent variable.

Comment: Do you think it is possible to use WLS weights and then export the weighted variable values instead? I was thinking perhaps I could do this and then use the exported values in my meta-regression.